# Can a public school district make a declaration condemning a foreign state?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, israel, education, hamas

A local board of education is considering making a declaration condemning Israel for the war between Israel and Hamas, similar to the one that certain Harvard student groups made in October 2023. Apparently, the board has been lobbied to do that by a number of parents who are Palestinian. Thus the question: can a public school board, an elected body in a public education system, make such declarations?

Comment: Why shouldn't they be able to?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution see JonathanReez's answer...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I expect this information to be in the question not in an answer. All "Can one do something?" questions should motivate why it would be expected to be a problem. This gives valuable context to answer the question more specifically.

Comment: They obviously *can*. The question is whether they should.

Comment: What do they gain by doing so?  It's unlikely that either Israel or Gaza will have a reason to care about the opinion of some random school board on the other side of the world.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, because inflammatory statements like that would put Israeli and Jewish kids in the position of likely harassment, just as that happened at CUNY, Harvard, Penn...

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the explanation. Please edit it in the question if not yet done so. People can then answer why this is not a problem despite the mentioned concerns or why these or other concerns indeed prohibit such a statement.

Comment: @Michael, are you arguing that any criticism of Israel's actions (no matter how horrendous they be) should be banned *in case* they lead to repercussions for Jews?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, specifically because anyone at any level of the US government, be it the local, state, or federal level, not to mention people outside of the government, can make almost any statement, subject to a few narrow limitations, and statements criticizing foreign governments fall into that much broader category. This freedom is guaranteed under the First Amendment to the Constitution of the United States of America, with few specific exceptions for government employees. The most famous of these is the [Hatch Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatch_Act?wprov=sfla1), but that only applies to federal employees and would not cover the statements in question.

Note that conceptually, this statement is not so different from many other, less contentious ones that schools often make: for instance, in support of action against climate change or gun violence. The same latitude that allows schools to make these sorts of statements also allows them to opine on foreign politics, or for that matter to [weigh in](https://www.pressherald.com/2016/04/01/school-board-members-endorse-colleague-for-portland-city-council/) [on domestic politics.](https://www.oklahoman.com/story/news/education/2021/04/07/lewis-hangs-on-for-tight-victory-okc-school-board-chair/7118893002/)

While the previous paragraphs should make it clear that no school board member is "disallowed" from making statements in the sense of facing criminal liability, it is worth mentioning that the school itself could be investigated by the Office of Civil Rights  if the statement was suspected to represent discrimination against students. However, not only is this unlikely to lead anywhere, since the statement explicitly took a stand against discrimination, including anti-Semitism, but such investigations are limited in what they can do. Pulling federal funding is the most extreme remedy, but is very rarely employed, for the simple reason that it primarily punishes students, including those whose alleged experiences with discrimination are the targets of such investigations. When such investigations do bear fruit—again, not particularly likely here—the typical result is a strong and legally irrelevant suggestion for the school to change its practices.

Since the school board members are elected officials, they can, of course, also be voted out in the next election if voters disagree with their positions. This is the same accountability any elected official faces. Depending on the district, they might also [be subject to a recall election](https://ballotpedia.org/States_that_allow_school_board_recalls)—again, as many public officials at the local level may be—or even [impeached](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mynbc15.com/amp/news/local/impeachment-case-filed-against-escambia-county-school-board-member).

Comment: One should also note that there are no real consequences of such statements. They describe the opinion of the school board on certain topics which may be of interest for students attending the school or people otherwise related to the school board but it has no impact whatsoever on the politicial topic they opined about.

Comment: Another example of limited speech that impacts school employees, including school boards, in many, but probably not all, states is advocating for funding during working hours or with school resources (ex: using a school email, even after hours).  My district has a millage vote coming up and though we are allowed to provide information regarding the millage, we're not allowed to advocate for it (or fight against it) in our roles as school employees.

Comment: @quarague same goes for the opinion of all but ~10 UN Member states. Doesn't really matter in the slightest what Chile or South Africa think about the conflict, they don't have the clout to change anything.

Comment: @JasonPatterson - If an employee did that, they might be fired. But the board is elected, so I think electoral accountability would be the only consequence for them.

Comment: Does the school district have an obligation to protect the Israeli and Jewish kids from the likely harassment that would follow such statements? Scratch "protect"; does the school district have an obligation not to **cause** discrimination and harassment by making inflammatory statements?

Comment: @Obie2.0 No, it's definitely illegal for anyone who is part of a school district (or other governmental organization) to use government funds in any manner (which includes anyone acting in a paid position) to advocate for funding.  I was able to find [the Ohio version of the law](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-9.03) - it's a 1st degree misdemeanor.

Comment: @Michael - I believe that I adequately address that in my paragraph on investigations by the Office of Civil Rights. That is the political organ that investigates allegations of discrimination in school systems. I also point out that consequences for the school system would be limited, and consequences for the board probably non-existent, if not electoral, even if it were found that the school system did engage in discrimination.

Comment: This answer appears to confuse personal speech by someone who happens to hold office in an institution with a spokesperson speaking on behalf of the institution.

Answer (score 7):

Can they? Yes, they clearly can and have [already done so](https://www.thejewishnews.com/jewish-telegraphic-agency/ann-arbor-school-board-endorses-call-for-ceasefire-in-israel-and-gaza/article_cc18da86-b604-11ee-871e-430dca21206e.html) (this is just one such declaration):

> The school board in this city endorsed a resolution calling for a ceasefire in the Israel-Hamas war early Thursday morning, more than five hours after convening for a meeting was expected to be contentious.
>
> The vote made Ann Arbor Public Schools one of the only school districts in the United States to adopt such a stance, three months after Hamas’ Oct. 7 attack on Israel ignited a war in Gaza and fierce debates in public bodies across the United States.

Will there be any consequences to their actions? Currently unclear, would depend on the outcome of an [investigation](https://www.timesofisrael.com/us-education-department-opens-new-antisemitism-probes-into-universities-schools/) by Federal authorities into the matter, due to potential discrimination against Jewish students at pro-Palestine schools:

> Complaints about anti-Israel protests at Temple University and Brown
> University filed by a Jewish right-wing activist who attends neither
> university are among the latest round of antisemitism investigations
> opened by the US Department of Education.
>
> The department’s civil rights office is also looking into a series of
> University of Minnesota faculty statements condemning Israel,
> following a complaint by a prominent Republican on the law school
> faculty.
>
> In addition, as of this week, the civil rights office has opened
> investigations at the two largest Bay Area public school districts,
> where some families have cited antisemitism concerns in applying to
> transfer out. And it is scrutinizing a private college where a Jewish
> anti-Zionist professor has publicly supported Hamas.

I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable to answer the question of whether this investigation will result in any fines to the school district.

Comment: Which law/ regulation or the school boards accused to have broken? Note that your source is from Israel, maybe there is a source from the US that better explains what the actual legal complaint is.

Comment: @quarague the accusation is “discrimination” against Jewish students. Whether or not it’s legitimate I do not know.

Comment: Wouldn't that run against 1st amendment?  Not that the school's is a very useful gesture to start with, but aren't 1st amendment challenges pretty hard to overcome?  Or is it one set of rules in some cases, another set when it suits better?  Do these big legal guns come out in cases where the Chinese govt gets condemned and which have Chinese students?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the idea is that the school is not _just_ making these statements but _also_ discriminating against students. Whether or not this is true I have no idea.

Comment: Just to be clear - upvoted, it answers the Q.  And, yes, mentioning that a bit of legal challenges/censorship is on the way is also a useful part of the answer.

Comment: So the investigation is not because of the statement of the schools but because there are accused of discriminating against students by religion.

Comment: @quarague the official rationale hardly matters, in practice it wouldn’t have happened if the school board wasn’t as public about their personal political ideology

Comment: @quarague: Even absent any discrimination, taking an official stance on foreign relations is arguably a breach of federal supremacy.

Answer (score -1):

> **Question:**
>
> Can a public school district make a declaration condemning a foreign state?

It's a rather bold move.  The school board that would make this declaration would have nothing to gain.  It stands for re-election regularly, so if the declaration was not supported by the community they could and would lose their positions pretty quickly.  I thus don't think they will do it.

Otherwise freedom of speech while not an absolute right in the United States,  this would fall under the right.  The ultimate accountability for the action is with the voters they represent.

Comment: Several boards in the U.S. have already done this, see my answer.

Comment: I mean they could gain popularity if the statement was popular with their constituents.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-,   agreed.